# Script not correctly printing the correct elements of the array

Tags: bash, shell-script, diff

So basically I have to write a bash script that examines some specific files from the working directory (which are named file.00.txt up to file.24.txt). The thing is, 3 of them are exatcly the same and my assignment is to create a script that tells me which 3 are the same.

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash 
f0=file.00.txt
f1=file.01.txt
f2=file.02.txt
f3=file.03.txt
f4=file.04.txt
f5=file.05.txt
f6=file.06.txt
f7=file.07.txt
f8=file.08.txt
f9=file.09.txt
f10=file.10.txt
f11=file.11.txt
f12=file.12.txt
f13=file.13.txt
f14=file.14.txt
f15=file.15.txt
f16=file.16.txt
f17=file.17.txt
f18=file.18.txt
f19=file.19.txt
f20=file.20.txt
f21=file.21.txt
f22=file.22.txt
f23=file.23.txt
f24=file.24.txt

array=($f0 $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 $f9 $f10 $f11 $f12 $f13 $f14 $f15 $f16 $f17 $f18 $f19 $f20 $f21 $f22 $f23 $f24)

i=0
touch placeholder

while [ $i -lt ${#array} ]
do
    DIFF=$(diff ${array[i]} ${array[i+1]})
    if [ "$DIFF" = "" ]
    then
        echo "${array[i]} y ${array[i+1]}" >> placeholder
    fi
i=$((i+1))
done

    cat placeholder
```

The idea of this code is to compare each file with the following one in the array , then store the ones that are the same in a file called placeholder and finally revealing the contents of the file with the cat command.

However, everytime I run the scrip I am getting the message

```
file.00.txt y file.00.txt
file.01.txt y file.01.txt
file.02.txt y file.02.txt
```

and so on for each file. This should not happen, since I am clearly using

```
echo "${array[i]} y ${array[i+1]}" >> placeholder
```

to echo both positions. Why is this happening and how can I solve this ?

How can I solve this?

Comment: You _do_ add a comma to the filename in the call to `diff`.  It may be worth removing that...  Apart from that, is there a reason for creating all those variables and _then_ add them to an array? Note too, that your loop is not terminated by a `done` and that you don't increment `i`, and that the length of the array is `${#array[@]}`, not 27, and that it's easier to loop over the elements of the array (`"${array[@]}"`) than to use an index (that is, if you need an array at all and can't just loop over `file.*.txt`).

Comment: Also you could just use brace expansion: `array=( file.{00..24}.txt )` to generate the file names. Though note that if you only diff files _n_ and _n+1_, you won't notice if _nonconsecutive_ files (e.g. 3 and 8) are the same, so the logic in the loop may need some more thought. (You'd need to look over each other file for each file.)

Comment: Ok so I corrected all these things but I am still not getting what I want to . I will edit to clarifi what I getting

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok so I am still new, so I did not know I could just loop over the files. How would I do that  without an array? Thnaks to both of you guys

Comment: Hi and welcome to unix.stackexchange.com.  In case you wonder about why your query did not meet with all the enthusiasm you expected, it is because, one gets the feeling that you did not properly research your problem before posting. It is generally considered good form not to do so BEFORE you ask others to finish yr HW.  To boot the first comment above by Kusalanada gives you useful pointers for you to learn about your issue**S**. You do not seem to have exploited that yet. If you did, edit your query so your progress is reflected.

Comment: Very bad algorithm anyway because you will do 27*26 comparisons. Try instead:  1) get the MD5 hash of the files (md5sum command), 2) count the instances of each hash (`sort | uniq -c` after extracting only the hashes fro the md5sum output), 3) find the biggest count (add `sort -n | tail i-1` to the pipeline), 4) extract the hash, 5) use `grep $hash` on the complete md5sum output to retrieve the names of the files with that hash. If paranoid, 6) use `cmp` to check that all three files are the same.

Comment: It would be easier/faster to use `cmp` and test for the return code than to use `diff` and check for an empty output.

Answer (score 1):

The seemingly strange output of your code could possibly be explained by the fact that your script only ever *adds* to the output file. This means that you might have had some error in your code previously (now corrected), but that you still see the output of that run in the output file, since the output file is never removed or emptied by the script.

---

You could shorten your script into

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( file.*.txt )

for name in "${array[@]}"; do
    if [ -n "$prev_name" ] && cmp -s "$prev_name" "$name"
    then
        printf '%s y %s\n' "$prev_name" "$name"
    fi

    prev_name=$name
done
```

This uses a globbing pattern to populate the array with the filenames matching the pattern.

It then loops over the names, comparing filenames that occur adjacent to each other in the array using `cmp -s`.  The `cmp` utility will exit with a *true* exit status if the contents of the two files that it's comparing are identical.

The loop uses `$prev_name` to hold the name of the previous file in the array. In the first iteration of the loop, this variable is empty, so the actual comparison of files is skipped.

---

What you are possibly *expected* to write is a double loop.  Something like

```
for nameA in "${array[@]}"; do
    for nameB in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [ "$nameA" != "$nameB" ] && cmp -s "$nameA" "$nameB"
        then
            printf '%s y %s\n' "$nameA" "$nameB"
        fi
    done
done
```

But this would compare `A` against `B` *and* `B` against `A`, and the number of calls to `cmp` would grow quadratically with the number of files involved, which would be both resource intensive (on disks; it would read *each file* as many times as there are filenames in the array) and slow.

---

A common way to find sets of files is with identical contents is with `fdupes`:

```
$ fdupes --sameline .
./file.1.txt ./file.2.txt ./file.7.txt
```

Would you want to do something similar without `fdupes`, you could do that by computing and comparing a checksum of each file using e.g. `md5sum`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A names count

while read -r cksum name; do
    names[$cksum]+=${names[$cksum]:+,}$name
    count[$cksum]=$(( count[$cksum] + 1 ))
done < <( md5sum file.*.txt )

for cksum in "${!count[@]}"; do
    if [ "${count[$cksum]}" -gt 1 ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${names[$cksum]}"
    fi
done
```

The first loop reads the output of `md5sum` which is is executed across all the relevant files.  The output of `md5sum` may look something like

```
897316929176464ebc9ad085f31e7284  file.1.txt
8c9eb686bf3eb5bd83d9373eadf6504b  file.10.txt
897316929176464ebc9ad085f31e7284  file.2.txt
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  file.3.txt
84bc3da1b3e33a18e8d5e1bdd7a18d7a  file.4.txt
aa6ed9e0f26a6eba784aae8267df1951  file.5.txt
6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  file.6.txt
897316929176464ebc9ad085f31e7284  file.7.txt
c30f7472766d25af1dc80b3ffc9a58c7  file.8.txt
9ae0ea9e3c9c6e1b9b6252c8395efdc1  file.9.txt
```

The checksum in the first column is read into `cksum` and filename gets read into `name`.

Inside the first loop, we append the name to an entry in an associative array that is indexed by the checksum.  The way the assignment to `names[$cksum]` is done there makes sure that we add a comma before each new name if needed (which it is if the entry already contains some other names).  We then update a count of the number of times that we've seen this particular checksum (this will be used in the second loop).

In the second loop, we go through the checksums (`"${!count[@]}"` expands to a list of keys (checksums) in the `count` associative array), and for each checksum we test whether its count is greater than 1, meaning we've found a duplicate file (if you're looking for groups of exactly three identical files, you may want to use `-eq 3` instead of `-gt 1` here).  If it is, we print the names associated with that checksum.

Testing it:

```
$ bash script.sh
file.1.txt,file.2.txt,file.7.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more efficient way of doing what you're trying to do. I use a smaller sample set to keep things clearer:

```
#!/bin/bash

# clear placeholder
printf "Files with no diff:\n" > placeholder

# set up sample data
echo "one" > file.00.txt
echo "one" > file.01.txt
echo "foo" > file.02.txt
echo "bar" > file.03.txt
echo "two" > file.04.txt
echo "two" > file.05.txt 

# generate array
i=0
while [ $i -lt 6 ]; do    
    array+=( file.`printf %02d $i`.txt )
    ((i++))
done

i=0
while [ $i -lt 5 ]; do
    diff --brief ${array[i]} ${array[i+1]} && \
    echo "${array[i]} ${array[i+1]}" >> placeholder 
    ((i++))
done
```

Results:

```
$ sh ./test.sh 
Files file.01.txt and file.02.txt differ
Files file.02.txt and file.03.txt differ
Files file.03.txt and file.04.txt differ
$ cat placeholder 
Files with no diff:
file.00.txt file.01.txt
file.04.txt file.05.txt
```

You don't need to generate sample data if you actually already have data.

The code, explained:

Building an array in a loop (in Bash) can be done by iterating the way you obviously already know, but the `array+=` notation appends an element.

The `((++))` obviously increments your counter.

Performing the diff, I use the `--brief` option. If you read the `diff` man page, it tells you that `--brief` only prints output when a difference is found. Therefore, the diff command *succeeds* if no diff is found.

Using the `&&` (AND) notation, this code echos the names of the files being compared into your `placeholder` file *if and only if* the `diff` command generates no output.

If there *is* a difference between files, `diff` outputs the differences to the terminal. This causes the `&&` (AND) to fail, so nothing is output to the placeholder file.

If you have any further questions about the syntax, feel free to ask.

Comment: "Because Bash interprets silence as success...", noo, not really. `&&` and `if` check the [exit code/exit status](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Exit_Status) of the command. `diff` just happens to return a truthy exit code (i.e. zero) if the files are identical, and a falsy exit code (a one) if they differ. But you can have commands that produce output and return a truthy value, or the other way around, e.g. `echo foo && echo "it's true"` or `false && echo "it's true"`

Comment: Yes, you're right, my comment was unintentionally broad there. I'll edit for accuracy. Thanks.